# Authorize.net Payment in Magento does not show credit card form when selected

Tags: magento, authorize.net

We have the onestepcheckout module installed and tried to enable authorize.net payment module by entering all the API info and transaction key properly.

But on checkout, no credit card form shows when selecting authorize.net.

We have also tried disabling the onestepcheckout module and even then it does not show the form. Upgrading to 1.6.2 does not solve the issue either. Can someone help?

Comment: support@onestepcheckout.com can help as this is a commercial extension that has free support

Comment: The issue was simple, in Config > Advanced, the setting for Display Mage_Paygate was set by default to Disabled.

Comment: thanks! dug through code for hours.

Comment: Btw, on StackOverflow (S.O.) an *encouraged* workflow when you discover the answer to your own question independent of S.O. is to answer it and accept your own answer.  Not only does it give people the opportunity to reward you for your good question and answer, it also makes the question more visible for future people, and encourages other people to post solutions.

Comment: @global-eyeglasses - did you see what Christopher Pfohl said?

Answer (score 8):

Because @global-eyeglasses is not posting an answer, I will:

in `Config -> Advanced`, the setting for `Display Mage_Paygate` was set by default to `Disabled`.